# Symfony - Get the state of the mail sended with Messenger

Tags: symfony, mailer, symfony-messenger, symfony-mailer

I'm currently using Symfony Messenger on my project. I'm using it to send mails through the MessageHandler

Heres the file :

```
<?php

namespace App\MessageHandler;

use App\Entity\Dossier;
use App\Message\SendEmailMessage;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

class SendEmailMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $em;
    /** @var MailerInterface */
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function __invoke(SendEmailMessage $message)
    {
        $email = (new Email())
        ->from('test@gmail.com')
        ->to('test@gmail.com')
        ->subject('test')
        ->html('test');

        $this->mailer->send($email);
    }

}
```

Is it a way to track the mail through Messenger to get a response from the smtp server or something like this ? I'd like to show the user if the mail was sent or not using Messenger

Answer (score 1):

You can track if the message failed when being handed off to the SMTP server through a try/catch block as showing at https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#handling-sending-failures

```
$email = new Email();
// ...
try {
    $mailer->send($email);
} catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
    // some error prevented the email sending; display an
    // error message or try to resend the message
}
```

However, if you're looking for further feedback, such as if the message was ultimately undeliverable (bounce, full mailbox, etc) then you'll want to look either into the management side of your mail server, or more into [third-party transports](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#using-a-3rd-party-transport), that will then issue a callback webhook that will later inform you of the status. Those service also provide great feedback such as if your message was marked spam by the recipient, etc.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I send a failed message on purpose to see if the failed message is correctly stored in my db ?

Comment: @AureSanta - the Symfony Mailer component *only throws an error* if the mail server defined in your `.env` file (specified by `MAILER_DSN`) rejects the message.. For instance, with an SMTP server, if it accepts your message for forwarding, Symfony **WILL NOT** won't trigger an error, even if the message later bounces or has an invalid email address. In essence, if your configured `MAILER_DSN` recipient accepts the message, Symfony won't generate an error. However, if such errors do occur, it's crucial to be promptly alerted because it likely means that no emails can be delivered.

Comment: If you are wanting to track or log the ultimate deliverability of a message, that is where something like third-party transports which then provides web-hooks back to your application. They will notify you when the message has been sent, received, read, or if it was bounced, reported as spam, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll check for third-party transports docs!